# In which format C program should export to run on linux?

Tags: c, bios, visual-studio-code

In windows we publish application in **.exe** format, so I have C program and I want to publish that application for linux. In which format I should publish it and how?

Comment: Publish an application for Linux or to run it from BIOS? Those are entirely different things and export formats.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov tell me about application for linux.

Comment: "Publish"? Do you mean compile?

Comment: @Panki yes. Exporting type

Comment: What do you mean by “exporting”? Is this still within the context of providing your program in an initrd?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes. Actually you know I was trying to run `exe` by wine command. but busybox doesn't have wine. So I am trying to publish my C program in specific file extension which supports linux directly. So later I can call it from `init`. Thanks

Comment: You have to not to "export it with specific extension" but to compile and link it to the target environment. In the initramfs of Linux the environment is pretty special, so you'll likely end up with static binary (that doesn't require dynamic libraries) or you will need to bring them together with an executable.

Comment: neither "publish" nor "export" mean what it seems you think they mean. Sadly, we don't know *what* exactly you mean. Can you try to find *different* words for what you mean, and explicitly explain what you mean with these?

Comment: In windows, we publish our code in executable file extension which is .`exe`. So I am trying to build equivalent of `exe` for linux. I hope now you get what I am looking for.

Comment: On Windows, compilers output executables with names like `program.exe`. On Linux and other Unix-style systems, compilers output executables with names like `program`, with no extension. There’s nothing special to do to “publish” your code.

Comment: Don't expect to have a compete guide as an answer. Nobody (in their right mind) will write such an answer. You **have** to do research **yourself**. You already have a starting point to begin your search.

Comment: I am already researching on it and didn't get anything that is why I come here @NikitaKipriyanov

Comment: I told you what to look for in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Main binary format that Linux uses is called [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), originally it was invented for Unix. `ld` program can produce (*link*) them from object files. Linux can also support different executable formats; it's possible to write a custom loader which will load Windows's "exe" (Portable Executable) files and run them.

By the way, ".exe" is not a format, but a file name extension. It used to have at least two different formats from Microsoft: [older DOS "MZ" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) and more recent [Windows PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Not only "exe" files have PE format; "dll" (dynamic libraries) have in principle the same structure, and many other files. Likewise, in Linux not only call-in binaries have ELF format, but shared dynamic libraries too, but usually those have ".so" as an extension, or ".so.1.3.4" (versioned form, digits represent the version of the library). Binaries that you call usually have no extension; the property to be an executable program comes from the file system attribute "executable", and is not inferred from the file name (extension).

However, the question is very broad. Try searching "linux c programming tutorial" to have a grasp what's the process of producing a binary executable looks like and then ask more concrete questions.